# JPA Hibernate Spring Data How to test queries without redeploy all project

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpql

How Can I test JPQL queries without redeploy all the project? Is there any tool I can query like the GUIs for relational debatases?

Comment: Write automated tests. That way, not only you can test your query without deploying and using your application, but you can restest it, again and again and again, every time you build your project, and thus detect regressions.

Comment: Yes, I have automated tests. But I would like a way of simple test queries like you do in a database GUI.